# Display Streaming output on Chainlit from AutoGPTQForCausalLM and RetrievalQA.from_chain_type

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, llama

Hello I'm creating Document QNA chatbot using `AutoGPTQForCausalLM` and `RetrievalQA.from_chain_type` and I want to display the Streaming output (like chatgpt) to provide better UX on chainlit.

I used TextStreamer and `streamer=TextStreamer(tokenizer,skip_prmpt=True, skip_special_tokens=True,verbose=True)` and integrated it to my pipeline. I'm using LLAMA2-13B-GPTQ model

Now I'm able to get a streaming output on my CLI but not able to get it on Chainlit UI.

Is there any way, I can show this streaming verbose or the final output in a streaming manner over CHainlit UI.

Thank you

Comment: sharing your code makes it easier to help